# Ansible ec2_instance_facts complaining boto3 is not installed (but it is)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Trying to retrieve AWS metadata with Ansible with a simply playbook like:

```
    ---
    - hosts: tag_mytagname_mytagvalue
      tasks:
        - ec2_instance_facts
        - ping
```

I get an error about boto3 being missing (although already installed)

> TASK [ec2_instance_facts]
>   ********************************************************************************************************** fatal: [ip-10-186-27-189.ec2.internal]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "msg": "boto3 required for this module"}

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be because Ansible is attempting to retrieve EC2 facts *on the remote host* (because that's what I told it to, d'Oh!)

Need to retrieve the facts using the localhost:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - ec2_instance_facts:
```

Credit to this reddit for the solution (but more useful to have it here on SF): https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/8p4l9f/awsec2_group_facts_error_boto3_required_for_this/

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exact error message in a similar situation -- when using the `ec2_instance_facts` module with `connection: local` (as part of a larger task list that mixes remote tasks with local ones):

```
---
- ec2_instance_facts:
  connection: local
```

The solution in that case is to use `delegate_to: localhost` instead of `connection: local`:

```
---
- ec2_instance_facts:
  delegate_to: localhost
```